# Celery/Django: shared_task tasks disappeared or not registering from task registry when starting a worker

Tags: django, celery

When booting up a worker, it lists all of the registered shared_tasks that can be consumed by the worker.

When adding "proper" code to one of the shared_tasks (rather than test code) all of sudden the tasks were not registering.

Answer (score -1):

Found this was because I was importing a constants file thusly:

```
from . import constants
```

and the constants file was actually in the folder above the tasks file.  There was no debug error at all, so putting here just in case someone has the same problem